# Realm Swift How to update an List object

Tags: swift, realm

I have a problem when I try to update a value on a List.
This is my DB model:

```
class User: Object {

@objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var height : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var age : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var sex : String = ""
@objc dynamic var physicalActivity : Double = 1.0
@objc dynamic var goal : String = ""
let weightProgress = List<WeightProgress>()
let calories = List<Calories>()

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"

}
}


class Calories : Object {

@objc dynamic var date : String?
@objc dynamic var eatenCalories : Int = 0

}
```

The main feature is, User put how many calories he ate, and save it to DB. Date is generated by `Date()` and convert to `String`. If next value has the same `Date` I want to updated existing `eatenCalories` property, if `Date` is different I want to create another record to DB.

Any ideas?

Now after each value adding it create another record in DB.

BR
iMat

Comment: Practically if your objects are generated through user input, two objects cannot have the same `Date` since they will at least differ by a few seconds. So to what precision do you want your dates to match? Btw storing dates in Realm as `String`s is a bad idea. Realm supports storing `Date` properties, so you should do so.

Comment: Im using SwiftDate pod to manage all `Date` objects. I want to store only Day, without time for example: 25.04.2018 (that format is mandatory - that is why i store it like a `String`)

Answer (score 0):

Adds or updates an existing object into the Realm. Only pass true to update if the object has a primary key. If no object exists in the Realm with the same primary key value, the object is inserted. Otherwise, the existing object is updated with any changed values.

you should use

> self.realm.add(item, update: true)

and you should add primary key to your object